# How to find user cellular data/talk time balance programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, core-telephony

I searched and found that iOS 7 has already blocked use of USSD code for security reason and in iPhones with < iOS7 we can dial a USSD code manualy but not programmatically.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:\*123* <2334555>#"]]?
```

This is not working in iOS 7.

Apple Documentation says:

> To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing
>   the behavior of a phone or account, the Phone app supports most, but
>   not all, of the special characters in the tel scheme. Specifically, if
>   a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone app does not attempt
>   to dial the corresponding phone number. If your app receives URL
>   strings from the user or an unknown source, you should also make sure
>   that any special characters that might not be appropriate in a URL are
>   escaped properly. For native apps, use the
>   stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: method of NSString to
>   escape characters, which returns a properly escaped version of your
>   original string.

Is there any way to programatically check user data/talk time balance?